# get list of files which are unique

Tags: ls, search

I have a directory in which files are created as `abc.sh.ID.datetimestamp.id.log`
In the filename abc.sh, the *ID* is always the same (there are 1000's of .sh's and ID's combination in the environment). *datetimestamp* and *id* change for each file generated. I am trying to use `ls -ltr abc.sh.*.log`. But it returns all filenames which match the expression. I need only unique ID filenames not caring what *datetimestamp* and *id* are.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: anyone who can help with this?

Answer (score 6):

I should think:

```
ls ./* | cut -d '.' -f 1,2,3 | sort -u
```

will get you there, this essentially lists the contents of the directory, then cuts off everything after the third '.' and then sorts the lines and removes duplicates. The end result would be a list of 'abc.sh.ID'.

If you want you loop through this new list and do an 'ls [line]*' to get the datetimestamp.id.log as well, which would result in the contents of the directory grouped by ID.

Comment: Dave thanks for your reply. When I run that it errors out giving 
ksh: /usr/bin/ls: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long.
I tried from bash as well it says: bash: /usr/bin/ls: The parameter or environment lists are too long. Other thing is I need "abc.sh" in the search for sure

Comment: @kumar2008 you can try using just `ls` the `./*` is redundant, but should be accepted (for whatever reason it sounds like all of the files in the directory are being passed as an argument). Alternatively you can replace `ls ./*` with `find ./`, you'll need to provide the `-maxdepth` option if there are directories in there as well though. The command I provided will still include the 'abc.sh.ID' as I mentioned.